# count of daily users in PostgresSQL where count zero is also added

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the below query to get count of users created

```
SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', created), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', created)
```

but the dates where count is 0 are not showing up.
i know about generate_series but i couldn't get it to work with it.

```
select date_trunc('day',created_at)as day,
count(id) as signup from users
where created_at between '2022-1-11' and  now()
group by 1
order by 1
```

I have tried re writing as above, but still doesn't work

How can get entry with where count is zero?

I tried using `generate_series()` but could not get the query correct.

Comment: *I tried using generate series* - you need to show your attempt; you can't count rows that aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

A left join with a generate_series call might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT j.d, count(u.*) 
FROM generate_series('2022-11-01'::date,CURRENT_DATE,interval '1 day') j (d)
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.created = j.d
GROUP BY 1;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/JNHTaad6)